# Image superposition with transparency in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I am trying to display a lung CT image as a background image and its ROI mask over the first image with transparency. The following image

[image]

Until now I have developed the following code:

```
load example.mat
fig = figure;
him = imagesc(img);
colormap(gray)
set(him, 'AlphaData', 0.3 * mask)
```

[image]

But it only display with transparency the region covered by the Mask. What I really want is the whole lung displayed with the Mask over it in some color like green.

This image is an example of what I am trying to reach.

[image]

This is the link for the file contaning the CT lung matrix and the Mask matrix.

[Link for the .mat file with the images](https://www.dropbox.com/s/phknxxbi5ji43wb/example.mat?dl=0)

Comment: So you want full transparency everywhere, but in the "mask" points, where you want only a bit transparency. Then you want the Green chanel of an RGB image to have the mask added, rigth? just this explanation should get you on track.

Comment: See: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100086-how-do-i-superimpose-images-in-matlab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I "plot" an image on top of another image with a different colormap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575844/how-can-i-plot-an-image-on-top-of-another-image-with-a-different-colormap)

Answer (score 1):

You can just overlay another image:

```
hold on
ih = image(cmask, 'AlphaData', mask.*.3, 'CDataMapping', 'direct');
```

Here, `cmask` is obtained for example by

```
cmask = zeros(size(mask, 1), size(mask, 2), 3);
cmask(:, :, 2) = mask.*255;
```

to get a green mask.